# Android WiFiManager Controlling

Tags: android, wifimanager

I would like to write a wrapper that will control the Android WiFi manager.
That means that I would be able to enable/disable it.

But that also means that I will decide also if the WiFiManager can get a command from another process.

Example:

- I set the WiFi disable
- I don't allow the user (or any other task) to enable it back.

I read that there the WifiManager.WifiLock command that can force the WiFi to be ON.
If I had the same command for force the WiFi to be OFF I would have gotten the full solution.

Do you have any idea how to implement such a feature.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you planning on writing your own custom build of the Android OS and placing it into your own custom ROM?

Comment: yes. I can build the full image

Comment: I also have the possibility to change the WiFi manager itself but I would like to avoid changing any android component.

Comment: It seems to be more tricky than I thought.... :-)

Comment: Can anyone advise for exmaple to "SUSPEND" the WifiManager module? We will definitely need to change the WiFiManager to accept or not commands from extrenal process. This flash being controlled by our module.